# AMXMLC "Error: Unable to locate specified base class 'spark.components.WindowedApplication'"

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4, mxmlc

I'm a newbee to AIR and Flex, and I've been having trouble using amxmlc to compile a .mxml file from the command line. Specfically, I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Unable to locate specified base class 'spark.components.WindowedApplication' for component class 'DesktopClient'.
```

Googling has informed me that this is commonly the result of attempting to use mxmlc to compile an AIR project, and all the solutions I have yet found suggest to use amxmlc instead. However, that is what I am already doing.

This is how I am using amxmlc on the command line:

```
/Users/samreha/Documents/Apache\ Flex/bin/amxmlc -library-path /Users/samreha/Documents/Apache\ Flex/frameworks/libs/air/airframework.swc --  DesktopClient.mxml
```

Answer (score 1):

A WindowedApplication is an AIR specific component.  You are essentially trying to compile an AIR application with a Flex compiler.

Comment: To my knowledge, amxmlc IS the AIR compiler, mxmlc is meant for Flex projects.